# Drawing smoother pixel trails with as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to make a slice effect when user moves his fingers on the screen on Android Device like in Fruit Ninja 
I have a movieClip named Particle which has a circle 
I tried following

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , stratSlice);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , endSlice); 
function startSlice(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE , drawSlice);
}
function endSlice(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE , drawSlice);
}
function drawSlice(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var p:Particle = new Particle();
    addChild(p);
    p.x = mouseX;
    p.y = mouseY;
}
```

but when I run it The slice is broken I want it to be seamless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding e.updateafterevent() in the mouse move handler might improve performance a bit.

In general your code will probably not work as well as other particle effects you see in games such as fruits ninja. For good results you will need to use a particle engine such as

StarDust: https://code.google.com/p/stardust-particle-engine/

Flint: http://flintparticles.org/

Partigen: http://www.desuade.com/partigen/engine

Starling Particle: https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Extension-Particle-System

I know starling works great on android, not sure about the others